# The number of tools in GIMP Toolbox have reduced. How to restore them?

Tags: 18.04, gimp

There used to be many tools in the GIMP Toolbox. However, recently after an Update, many of the tools in the Toolbox seems to have been removed. How do I restore the original layout of the Toolbox?

Current Toolbox with less tools:

[image: gimp toolbox issue]

```
$ snap list | grep gimp
gimp                     2.10.18                     252   stable    snapcrafters
```

I just tried to run gimp from the command line and found the below msg. I also see this msg in other computer.

```
$ gimp
ln: failed to create symbolic link '~/snap/gimp/252/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': File exists
/snap/gimp/252/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Widgets-WARNING: parse_iso_codes: error parsing '/build/gimp/parts/gimp/install/usr/share/xml/iso-codes/iso_639.xml': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the new default, you can read more about it in the [release news](https://www.gimp.org/news/2020/02/24/gimp-2-10-18-released/)

You can turn it off in **Edit ➤ Preferences ➤ Interface/Toolbox ➤ Use tool groups**